# BlackBerry - change the application name for an existing project

Tags: blackberry

I have a BlackBerry project named "A".  This means the build produces artifacts named A.alx, A.cod and all that.

Now I want to change the application name to "B". I tried changing the output file name to "B" and built the project. I get the output B.COD, B.alx etc. But when I try to install B.alx onto the BlackBerry device with the Desktop manager, it does not install, saying "this is not compatible application". This happens even though I can install A.alx successfully.

I made sure I am using 4.7 JDE to install on 4.7 device. I know I am doing something wrong when renaming the application in the project files. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem. I think you need to rename your whole project to B so that its output would be B.cod.

Comment: FYI. No need to rename the entire project. Follow what Fostah and Michael Donohue says, that worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a dash or space character in an application output filename.   Make sure your "B" name does not include one.

**edit**

If you want to use those characters, edit the application title in the app descriptor.  That is what the user sees when your app is installed.

Comment: I want my application to be displayed on the device with two words for ex "My App". If my app name has space like that, and trying to install .alx file, Desktop manager throwing error as "this is not compatible application". If i don't give space for Output file, for ex: "MyApp", i'm able to install it. How can i provide my application name with space and two words, something like "My App" . I am seeing there are many third party applications have two words in their app names. How it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some steps for changing project settings within the JDE:

1. Right click on the project and choose "Properties". A properties dialog will open.
2. In the "General" tab, you can edit the title of the project (This is what will be displayed on the ribbon), the version and some other stuff.
3. In the "Build" tab you can change the name of the output files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I did the same thing. The new output file is created the .alx, .cod etc. files. But when i try to install thru Desktop Manager or Javaloader command, it's not installing and giving me the error as "this is not compatible application". I think, project file name, class file names should be same as "Properties" title and "Output file" names ?